# An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project". Version 8 of project facet java does not exist

Tags: java, maven, spring-tool-suite

While updating my Maven project on Spring STS 4.4.19 I am getting this error:

[image: 1]

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
Version 8 of project facet java does not exist.
```

I am using Java 11.  I want to fix this error.

Comment: See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=582041